# Scope variable data not changing in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I want to change scope vairable data by below code but it is not working. I am not getting any error but it is not working like expected.

```
$scope.secondcity1 = false;
$scope.hidecity1 = function() {
  alert(secondcity1);
  $scope.secondcity1 = false;
  $scope.city1 = ''; 
  alert(secondcity1);
}
```

I am using alert(secondcity1); this to show alert box but it is not showing anything,

```
<div ng-style="{'display':secondcity1 == false?'none':'block'">  
  <!-- some codes -->
  <button type="button" class="remove" ng-click="hidecity1()">-</button>
</div>
```

above code is also not working. I am expecting to hide the div but it is not hiding it.

Comment: use $scope in alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, in AngularJs to access objects you have to use `$scope` like `$scope.object`

```
$scope.secondcity1 = false;
$scope.hidecity1 = function() {
        alert($scope.secondcity1);
        $scope.secondcity1 = false;
        $scope.city1 = ''; 
        alert($scope.secondcity1);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me try. Voted up.

Comment: well alert is working but divs are not getting hidden. Please advise.

Comment: try this 
`<div ng-hide="!secondcity1">  
  <!-- some codes -->
  <button type="button" class="remove" ng-click="hidecity1()">-</button>
</div>`

Answer (score 1):

Your alert should display the **`$scope`** variable, otherwise it will be undefined

Change

**`From`**

```
alert(secondcity1);
```

**`To`**

```
alert($scope.secondcity1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me try. Voted up.

Comment: well alert is working but divs are not getting hidden. Please advise.